# Outlook Addin 2010 event for ribbon tab load

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook

I have ribbon tab with number of buttons for the outlook addin (2010). I need to enable the buttons, depending on the which folders(inbox,sentItems, Draft etc), user clicks in.
For ex: if user is on the draft button, i want to disable button 1.
If user is on sent items folder, i want to enable the button.

Let us know which event should be picked for this functionality.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your ribbon XML must specify a callback (and implement it of course) that returns the enabled state of the button (getEnabled attribute). You can force a refresh of your control by calling IRibbonUI.Invalidate. IRibbonUI can be retrieved from the OnLoad callback of your ribbon.